# How can I find the visible columns of a list in Sharepoint?

Tags: c#, .net, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

I'm using the SharePoint object model.  I haven't seen a way to do this in MSDN's documentation...

Comment: "Visible" only applies to a view, not the list.  You have to check the view in question to see if a column is viewable.

Comment: hmm, well the code below seems to work.  Is this different than what you are talking about?

Comment: It does appear to work.  You might see if the columns that that's returning as hidden are the system columns or not.  If you've got heavily customized lists with lots of views, then you might want to check a specific view.  Depends on your use case I guess.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ended up going this route.  Sort of brute force but it works:

```
        SPList l = SPContext.Current.Web.Lists[new Guid(ddl_Lists.SelectedValue)];
        List<string> visFields = new List<string>();
        foreach (SPField field in l.Fields)
        {
            if (!field.Hidden)
            {
                visFields.Add(field.Title);
            }
        }
```

Hope it helps someone!

Answer (score 5):

Fields you see is based on current View. Use SPList.[DefaultView](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.splist.defaultview.aspx) to get default view. You can also use SPList.[Views](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.splist.views.aspx) to get any view.

For an SPView class, you can use [ViewFields](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spview.viewfields.aspx) property to get view fields.